# Is it possible to call a vb cls file in java

Tags: java, vb6, java-native-interface, vb6-migration

Is it possible to call a vb6 class file like (example.cls) in java by any means? if its possible can you suggest how it can be implemented like where should i start looking.

Comment: No. You can't call stuff from a source (cls) file. If you have the compiled version of the vb6 code in a dll, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30622185/5623232) may help.

Comment: That linked answer is a bit iffy, you cannot by default export functions from a VB DLL.

Comment: Compile the class in an ActiveX DLL (COM Server) project & register the resulting DLL, then from Java you can use com4j to create an instance of it & access its interfaces.

Comment: Rather than use COM, it's probably easier to rewrite the whole thing in Java, considering the availability of the source :)

Comment: Actually vb class is calling **advpi32.dll** for encryption so

Comment: You may be able to use advpi32.dll directly from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't call a vb class directly from java. you need to do the following

- Compile the VB6 class into dll file in VB6
- Then register the dll file in your system
- Call the dll file using java native